# Pull and merge remote branch changes with multiple heads

Tags: mercurial

When my current branch has more than 2 heads and I try to pull and merge with the remote changes, I get the following exception:

> abort: branch 'default' has 3 heads - please merge with an explicit rev
>   (run 'hg heads .' to see heads)

I am struggling to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what commands you are using to do this before you get the error.

Comment: @Nanhydrin hg pull and hg merge...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'hg merge -r rev' to merge with an explicit revision.

Comment: As you already said yourself the repository had multiple heads. As the merge command takes 2 changesets to merge and there are 2 heads the merge command knows the magic. But with multiple heads it doesn't know what to do. You know what changesets to merge so you need to tell that to the merge command by using -r. If you want useful information you can use 'hg help merge' to see what it does and what options you can give.